# Jquery delegate function on ajax populated select box (jquery 2.0)

Tags: jquery, delegates

I populate my selectbox with options onload (ajax, on pageload) and that works fine

```
<select name="variety" id="resorts"><option value="">Select </option></select>
```

To trigger a selected option (go to Url) I use the function below.

```
("body").delegate("#resorts","change", function(e){ 
    window.location='http://skiweather.eu/webcams/' + $(this).children("option:selected").attr("value");
    return false;
});
```

It does not seem to work it returns 'undefined'. What is wrong.

Maybe the populate function?

```
function populate_cantons(){$.getJSON("http://skiweather.eu/v3/ajax/fetch_canton.php",{country:$("#country").val()},function(a){var b=$("#cantons");var c=b.prop("options");$("option",b).remove();$.each(a,function(a,b){c[c.length]=new Option(b["canton"])});b.prepend("<option selected>Select region</option>")})}
```

http://skiweather.eu/latest/ (selectbox at the top right of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).children("option:selected").attr("value");
```

You try to read the `value` attribute, but your `option` elements have no such attribute. Either you add it or you read the text of the `option` element.

Comment: I prefer adding the value to the populate function, but I am a bit confused on how to do that..

Comment: The value attribute can be provided as the second argument to the `Option` constructor. So for the cantons it's `new Option(b["canton"], b["canton"])` for the resorts probably `new Option(b["resort_us"], b["resort_us"])`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("body").delegate("change", "#resorts", function(e){ 
   window.location='http://skiweather.eu/webcams/' + $(this).val();
   return false;
});
```